# How can I turn my iPhone into a tv remote control?

Tags: iphone, remote-control

Which software/hardware can turn my iPhone into a decent remote control for my TV?

(Are there any reviews out there that compare the options?)

Comment: Do you want it to be an IR remote, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an IR dongle (the iPhone doesn't natively have any IR capabilities). Google for iPhone IR remote and you'll see several options.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the new internet-connected TVs can be controlled via WiFi using apps available in the App Store. Here's an example for [2010 model Samsung Internet@TVs](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tv-remote/id359580639?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

The [Griffin Beacon](http://www.griffintechnology.com/beacon) looks like it should do what you want. It combines an iPhone app with an IR emitter that you place on a table and control via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

My entertainment system is basically a PC plugged in to a flat screen TV, so I've found apps like this work well:

http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/02/06/touch-mouse-from-logitech-turns-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch-into-a-keyboard/